# DS4 discharging while off

Tags: controllers, ps4

I use the Official PowerA Charging Dock to charge my DS4 controllers (2), it's very close to the PS4.

The story so far:

I charged my controllers to 100% (~10pm), put my PS4 in standy-by mode (orange light), shutdown my controllers and left Infamous SS downloading. The next day I came to play (~17:30pm) and both controllers were all dead, near 0% battery, how is that possible?

Comment: It can't be natural discharge. The DS4's battery takes several days to completely discharge naturally. Maybe your batteries are dead; ideally batteries are best kept between 20% and 80% charge, the longer you keep them below 20% or above 80%, the faster they'll degrade until they can't be used anymore. Under normal use (and normally people don't really care about the battery's ideal state) the battery should last 6 - 12 months before degradation becomes noticeable. Even if you kept your DS4 at 100% charge 24/7, it should take 3 - 6 months for the battery to die.

Comment: Well... it looks like there may be a support issue here. I found [this discussion](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Peripherals-Support/Dualshock-4-Battery-Discharges-While-Off/td-p/42276319) over on Sony's community forums where quite a few people are complaining of this issue. It might be worth contacting customer support over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old post, but for future reference to any Google Searchers:

It's because Sony either cheaped out on the circuit design, or built it improperly. I figured out why this happens myself: If the USB port is not supplying power, (like you turn your computer or PS4 off completely, but leave the controller plugged into it) the wire that you connect to the DS4 is continually discharging its battery even if the controller itself is also turned off. It bleeds its charge out into the wire with no way to stop it other than disconnecting the controller at the micro-USB plug. It has no shunt, basically.

Sony, of course, shouldn't have designed it this way so that you could leave a USB cable attached to the controller for ease of plugging it back into the computer or console between sessions... As it is, you MUST remember to detach the charge cable from the controller if the host device you plug it into is powered down.

Even if you were to unplug the full sized USB connector from the PS4 or PC, but leave the charge cable attached to the controller, it will still do this because the cable itself is responsible for leeching out the controllers battery charge.

So, no. The answer to this question is that it's not a normal case of natural battery discharge. It's a faulty design.